# Android: default filtering of acceleration and gyroscope data?

Tags: java, android, real-time, accelerometer, lowpass-filter

I was wondering if there is any information regarding the preprocessing of acceleration and gyroscope data in Android? If there is nothing done in software, the programmeable low pass of the mems sensor itself must be configured somehow. Is it always set to the highest cut off frequency or what do they do?

I know it's a very specific question, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get to know about it?

Comment: no.………………………...